# How to provision .aspx pages to site definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-definition, aspx

Is it possible to add custom .aspx pages to site definition. If yes, How we can do this ?
Please provide some example if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way as for WebTemplates,almost. You add the module directly in the onet.xml instead of in a separate feature.

See how Microsoft is doing it by looking for example on the onet found in Site Templates --> STS in the 14 or 15 hive